# Sawtooth tkinter mainloop frame duration?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Trying to animate a sequence of PIL images using tkinter. The graph of my frame durations (ms) looks like this:
[image: sawtooth frame duration]

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this spiky sawtooth pattern?

Here's a script to reproduce:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import Tkinter

import time
import sys

def generate_frames(n):
    """
    keep n under 101 * 101
    """
    out = []
    last_pil = None
    for i in range(n):
        if last_pil:
            pil_image = last_pil.copy()
        else:
            pil_image = Image.new('L', (101, 101), 255)   
        x = i / 101
        y = i % 101
        pil_image.load()[x, y] = 0
        out.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image))
        last_pil = pil_image

    return out

def draw():
    FRAME_COUNT =5000

    master = Tkinter.Tk()

    w = Tkinter.Canvas(master, width=302, height=302)
    w.create_rectangle(49, 49, 252, 252)
    w.pack()

    frames = generate_frames(FRAME_COUNT)

    def draw_frame(f, canvas_image):
        print repr(time.time())
        frame = frames[f]
        if canvas_image is None:
            canvas_image = w.create_image((151, 151), image=frame, anchor='center')
        else:
            w.itemconfigure(canvas_image, image=frame)

        w.current_frame = frame  # save a reference
        next_frame = f + 1
        if next_frame < FRAME_COUNT:
            master.after(1, draw_frame, next_frame, canvas_image)
        else:
            sys.exit(0)

    master.after(10, draw_frame, 0, None)
    master.mainloop()


draw()
```

To see the plot, pipe output through

```
import sys

last = None
for line in sys.stdin:
    value = float(line.strip()) * 1000
    if last is None:
        pass
    else:
        print (value - last)
    last = value
```

then through

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import sys

X = []
Y = []

for index, line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
    line = line.strip()
    X.append(index)
    Y.append(float(line))

pyplot.plot(X, Y, '-')
pyplot.show()
```

Making it multi-threaded doesn't help:

[image]

```
class AnimationThread(threading.Thread):

    FRAME_COUNT = 5000

    def __init__(self, canvas):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.frames = generate_frames(self.FRAME_COUNT)

    def run(self):
        w = self.canvas
        frames = self.frames
        canvas_image = None
        for i in range(self.FRAME_COUNT):
            print repr(time.time())
            frame = frames[i]
            if canvas_image is None:
                canvas_image = w.create_image((151, 151), image=frame, anchor='center')
            else:
                w.itemconfigure(canvas_image, image=frame)
            w.current_frame = frame
            time.sleep(1 * .001)

def draw_threaded():
    FRAME_COUNT = 5000
    master = Tkinter.Tk()

    w = Tkinter.Canvas(master, width=302, height=302)
    w.create_rectangle(49, 49, 252, 252)
    w.pack()

    animation_thread = AnimationThread(w)
    animation_thread.start()

    master.mainloop()

    animation_thread.join()

draw_threaded()
```

Comment: I would try running the animation in a separate thread, not in the tkinter mainloop and see what happens.

Comment: Good idea - thanks. It didn't make a difference though (see edited post)

Comment: Have you tried profiling it with `python -m cprofile <script-name>`?

Comment: Yeah - 74% of total time is in the tkinter built-in mainloop method and 15% of it is in the tkinter built-in call method. The remaining 10% is spent in generate_frames and initializing tkinter. So I guess what I'm wondering is what is going on inside of the tkinter mainloop c code that causes this.

Comment: I don't get the same behavior, see http://i.imgur.com/O1p3w.png and http://i.imgur.com/i91t5.png (this second one using `after` 20 ms). You are being very aggressive here, this is a huge task to do each 1 ms for such a general implementation of Tk. So, I believe this is to be dealt entirely in the realm of Tcl/Tk and not at Python at all. Also, it is known that using `itemconfigure` with images is slow. For instance, I changed the code to delete and recreate images, without much change in the plots (although someone could, correctly, expect a much worse performance).

Comment: Have you considered changing the way your animation loop executes its frames? Rather than `do-stuff-that-takes-variable-time => wait-for-fixed-time`, you should try out `do-stuff-async => if-time-is-right-continue-else-skip`.

Comment: This is quite possibly due to the garbage collection cycle - you'll typically get this kind of pattern. I'm not sure what you can do to help it along, though.

Comment: I've had similar issues drawing at high framerates to a `wx.glcanvas.GLCanvas`. Is your display adaptor set up to sync to vertical refresh?

Answer (score 2):

That closely resembles this kind of interference pattern when competing 60 and 50 Hz samples mingle:

[image: Interference Pattern of competing 60 Hz and 50 Hz samples]

[(Original Wolfram|Alpha plot)](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28120*pi*x%29sin%28100*pi*x%29)

This is likely caused by having two things at different (but close) refresh rates.  It's the same type of thing that happens when you try to film a TV screen and it looks like a black bar keeps moving down the image, or when car wheels appear to rotate backwards around their axles in car commercials.  It is essentially an extension of the [Moiré Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern).

I don't know whether or not it is caused by video drivers and/or hardware, but it is almost certainly caused by interfering cyclical patterns.  It looks a lot like it should be the GC cycle interfering with your `for` loop (hence the sudden drop in the sawtooth-like wave as memory is freed up and can be allocated)